# send ASP.Net Control Id To a JavaScript Function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have 2 views. The last control on view1 is txtName & the first control on view2 is txtAge. Need to change the focus from txtName to txtAge on TAB press, but I fail to acheive this.

ASPX:

```
<asp:Multiview ID ="multiview1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
  <asp:view ID="view1" runat="server">
  <asp:Textbox id="txtName" runat="server" 
onfocusout="SetFocus('<%=txtAge.ClientId%>');"></asp:TextBox>
  </asp:view>

<asp:view ID ="view2" runat="server">
   <asp:Textbox id="txtAge" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
</asp:view>
</asp:Multiview>
```

JS:

```
function SetFocus(controlId){
    /*alert(controlId);*/
 document.getElementById(controlId).focus();
}
```

When I check the alert, it shows `<%=txtAge.ClientId%>` in the popup. Where is this going wrong.

Here is my new finding:

This code works well when the target control is in the same view, but when it is in another view, then it doesnt. So I think, something else should also be done to change the view first and then worry about the focus:

```
<asp:Textbox id="txtName" runat="server" 
onfocusout="SetFocus();"></asp:TextBox>

function SetFocus(){
 document.getElementById('<%=txtEmail.ClientID%>').focus();
 /* txtEmail is in the same view 'view1' as in txtName */
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have a "View" control inside of "Multiview" one?

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated my question.

Comment: I am trying to use this js code as a common model for many such pages that I have.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Seems the issue is with the Multiview control. I updated my new finding in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting it in server-side code:

```
txtName.Attributes["onfocusout"] = String.Format("SetFocus('{0}');", txtAge.ClientId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is sufficient to use `tabindex`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178231%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

that uses build in features rather then javascript.

if you use asp.net 4.x you can use clientidmode=static 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

```
<asp:Multiview ID ="multiview1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
    <asp:view ID="view1" runat="server">
        <!-- other controls -->
        <asp:Textbox id="txtName" runat="server" TabIndex="1"/>
    </asp:view>
    <asp:view ID ="view2" runat="server">
        <asp:Textbox id="txtAge" runat="server" TabIndex="2"/>
        <!-- other controls -->
    </asp:view>
</asp:Multiview>
```

**edit**
if you do not mind using jQuery. You can wrap a div around `<asp:View..` and then do something like:

```
$("div.view input:last-child").on("change", function(){
    $(this).parent().next().find("input:first-child").focus();
});
```

please keep in mind that this is pseudo code. It is just an idea.

Comment: Thank you. But apologies. I meant to say views.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the aspx code. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Ah. Did not work. Also, its hard this way, as there are numerous controls, and so the idea for a common function for all such pages

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it's any better.

```
 <asp:Textbox id="txtName" runat="server" 
onfocusout='<%= String.Format("SetFocus(\"{0}\");", txtAge.ClientId) %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: try replacing `<%=` with `<%#`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set an attribute using an inline block in that situation... as you can see you are getting the literal `<%=txtAge.ClientId%>` text, and you are not getting the processed value that you are expecting.

You have two obvious solutions...

The first one (which Yuriy has already given you in his answer) is to set it from the code behind...

```
txtName.Attributes["onfocusout"] = String.Format("SetFocus('{0}');", 
                                                 txtAge.ClientId);
```

*(Disclaimer, I don't know what the `MultiView` is, as I've never used it, so I'm not 100% sure the 2nd option below will actually work in your scenario. Also, it is untested code.)*

The other is to use what Murali provides in his answer, but with additional manipulation...

```
<asp:Textbox id="txtName" runat="server" onfocusout="SetFocus(this);" />

function SetFocus(nameCtrl) {
  var ageId = nameCtrl.id.replace(/txtName/,"txtAge");
  var ageCtrl = document.getElementById(ageId);
  ageCtrl.focus();
}
```

Comment: It did not work. I tried to shift focus to a control in the same view, but still it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

Change line `onfocusout="SetFocus('<%=txtAge.ClientId%>');"></asp:TextBox>`
as `onfocusout="SetFocus('txtAge');"></asp:TextBox>`

You don't need to send ClientId