# Place cusor after text in ASP.NET Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

If it was Windows Forms, I could have used

```
textbox1.Select(textbox1.Text.Length,0);
```

How can I achieve this in C#, for an ASP.Net Textbox. I would like to do this only in C#

Comment: If you can get c# running in the client-browser you earn a medal. You can't from c# alone

Comment: And no, you can't do this in ONLY c#. A text box is a client-side object, c# is server side.

Comment: How come, we have option to set focus from server side, but not place a cursor. I guess, JS is the only way. Its just that, for the life of me, am unable to send the textbox ID to the js function.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543075/send-asp-net-control-id-to-a-javascript-function

Answer (score 1):

You must register appropriate javascript script [to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067469/selecting-all-text-in-html-text-input-when-clicked) on the page load (or any other way to run javascript). You can not achieve such behaviour on server side.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me (works in chrome and IE)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBranch" runat="server" onfocus="this.value=this.value;">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Courtesy: [Use JavaScript to place cursor at end of text in text input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511088/use-javascript-to-place-cursor-at-end-of-text-in-text-input-element)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can call Focus method from code behind.

It basically places a cursor inside TextBox using JavaScript, when the page is loated at client side.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textbox1"></asp:TextBox>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox1.Focus();
}
```